# Windows XP inbound networking fails after SP3 upgrade

Tags: windows-xp, windows-networking

With a Windows XP x86 SP2 machine[that worked fine before the OS upgrade]:

Upgraded the machine to XP SP3 using `WindowsXP-KB936929-SP3-x86-ENU.exe`

Now the machine can't be pinged, and other computers on the network can't connect to it using the `\\192.168.1.100\` style of addressing.

However, outbound connections work fine.  It can access other computers (ping, accessing file-shares, web browsing) and weirdly, it can ping itself.

- Firewall isn't enabled (windows firewall service not running).
- Don't see any 3rd-party firewall products installed.
- Netmask seems to be set correctly on all machines
- Installing IPv6 protocol (suggested on some forums) doesn't help.
- `netsh int ip reset` (suggested [here](http://winhlp.com/node/125#Networking_problems_after_installing_Service_Pack_2)) doesn't help
- It's not a network issue, as the machine can make outbound connections
- Going back to SP2 (either via disk-image, or uninstalling SP3) makes everything work again

Comment: Did you try reinstall of your NIC drivers?

Comment: What error message do other computers get when they try to ping this PC ?

Comment: You sure the address didn't change?  There is no technical reason it shouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The Windows Firewall service was disabled before the upgrade.

The SP3 upgrade changed that setting to Enabled, but didn't also change the "Hardware profile: Profile 1: Disabled"

So after the upgrade, the service wasn't running (hence a "you can't change firewall settings" message) but for some reason it thought that the firewall should be enabled.